# Nested loops in angular 2

Tags: angular

I want to display the data of this array:

```
array = [
{nom: nom1, composants: [composant11, composant12]}, 
{nom: nom2, composants: [composant21, composant22]}
]
```

I want to display it this way in a table:

**composant**      **nom**

composant11   nom1

composant12   nom1

composant21   nom2

composant22   nom2

This is my code:

```html
<table>
<tr>
<th>Composant</th>
<th>Nom</th>
</tr>
<template *ngFor="let item of array">
<template *ngFor="let composant of item.composants">
<tr>
<td>{{composant.nom}}</td>
<td>{{composant.code}}</td>
</tr>
</template>
</template>
</table>
```

My browser is not showing anything. I wonder if really there is a way to do that in the template. Or if I should first transform the array in the component before displaying it.
Any suggestion will be appreciated!

Comment: just one question ...is your array a public? or private?.. can youpost also your ts code?

Comment: The array is public

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try this:

```
rows = [
    {nom: "nom1", composants: ["composant11", "composant12"]}, 
    {nom: "nom2", composants: ["composant21", "composant22"]}
];

<table>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let row of rows">
        <tr *ngFor="let composant of row.composants">
            <td> {{ composant }} </td>
            <td> {{ row.nom }} </td>
        </tr>  
    <ng-container>  
</table>
```

Comment: @Fali: this will print the output of `array`. But I want the display to be inside a table, as I mentionned in my question.

Answer (score 2):

Change code like below:

```
    <table>
<tr><th>Composant</th> 
<th>Nom</th>
</tr>
<template *ngFor="let item of array">
<template *ngFor="let composant of item.composants">
 <tr> <td>{{item.nom}}</td> <td>{{composant|json}}</td> 
</tr>
</template> 
</template> 
</table>
```

Comment: It doesn't make any difference

Comment: It makes difference ,because item include nom and composants but composant doesn't include nom..

Answer (score 1):

I use a bit of a different syntax that got the job done

http://plnkr.co/edit/Z94BxYiu2UTU7h3oySui?p=preview

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>Composant</th>
<th>Nom</th>
</tr>
<template ngFor #item [ngForOf]="array">
  <template ngFor #noo [ngForOf]="item.composants">
    <tr>
      <td>{{noo}}</td>
      <td>{{item.nom}}</td>
    </tr>
    </template>
</template>
</table>
```